# Getting error when generating an excel file from the database query returned over 23000 rows

Tags: export-to-excel

I am getting an error when trying to generating an excel file from the database query returned over 23000 rows. But for the less number of rows it is giving the correct excel file.

Can you please tell me whether this kind of limitation exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your issue, provide the answer of following question.

1. What is the Row Count of your query?
2. What Error you are getting?
3. Excel which version using you are?

Excel 2003 has limitation of 65536 rows, if your query is returning more than 65536 rows then use Excel 2007 (1048576 Rows).

Comment: Thanks Arun. The problem were in some where else. At the time of creating the XML File, some special character was giving the error. I marked this as answered because, the information you gave may help others.